# I cannot find the missing operand in chmod command. (PS: I am new to linux)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, chmod

I am trying to run this command

```
chmod +xElecrow-LCD5
```

But I get in return

> chmod: missing operand after '+xElecrow-LCD5'
> Try 'chmod --help' for more information

I really dont know what to do.
I am using Raspbian 32 bit full version. Downloaded today from the Official Raspberry Pi Imager.

Comment: Are you missing a space between `+x` and `Elecrow-LCD5`? Right now the `chmod` is missing a third argument, and I strongly suspect it's because you accidentally combined the second and third.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a missing space between the "+x" and "Elecrow-LCD5"
try:

```
chmod +x Elecrow-LCD5
```